# Best Cross Platform Installer

Tags: installation

I would like to get your opinion about the best cross platform installer for mac windows for C++ application.

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

This is non trivial question as C++ builds are platform specific. You may need look at what Qt framework provides, as it is the only solution for C++ I know that pays attention to multi platform support.